# how to process params from react frontedn in phoenix api?

Tags: reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

Hey I am sending a request to my backend that looks like this:

```
  axios
.post(PAYMENT_SERVER_URL, {
  description,
  email: token.email,
  source: token.id,
  subscriptionID
}
```

and in the api the call arrives but it only works if i comment out the contents of the post request.
I tried to use schema and changeset to make it usable but no avail yet.

```
 use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "objs" do
    field(:description)
    field(:email)
    field(:source)
    field(:subscriptionID)
  end

  def changeset(obj, params \\ %{}) do
    obj
    |> cast(params, [:descriprion, :email, :source, :subscriptionID])
  end

  def create(_conn, params) do
    changeset(params)
    //log it out
  end
end
```

error message :

```
iex(1)> [info] OPTIONS /api/users
iex(1)> [debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for OPTIONS /api/users (MyApiWeb.Router)
    (myApi) lib/myApi_web/router.ex:1: MyApiWeb.Router.__match_route__/4
    (myApi) lib/phoenix/router.ex:307: MyApiWeb.Router.call/2
    (myApi) lib/myApi_web/endpoint.ex:1: MyApiWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
    (myApi) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: MyApiWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
    (myApi) lib/myApi_web/endpoint.ex:1: MyApiWeb.Endpoint.call/2
    (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:16: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
    (cowboy) c:/jsproject/myApi/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your passing a struct to that changeset. Maybe the problem?

Comment: @Bitwise is it not possible to just use the params by itself? do i need to cast it? also I added the error message in the post

Comment: It looks like you still need to create a route and a controller action AKA an "endpoint" for the request to hit.

Comment: yeah i got that too, i changed my post to options and it is working now, but i have a new problem now that the request arrives but the params shows empty:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454195/pheonix-api-options-call-shows-empty-params

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you are creating a User with that request. Your create action would look like this:

```
def create(_conn, params) do
  changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, params)
  //log it out
  Repo.insert(changeset)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided error message leaves us with two possibilities:

1. The client logic is buggy
2. The backend is somehow mapping the `POST` method to `OPTIONS`

The latter seems unlikely, so I would put my money on the client being the culprit. Further analysis would require additional information.

#### A side note on `OPTIONS`

`OPTIONS` is meant to be used on a resource to find out which methods are allowed (`GET`, `POST` etc.). It's defined as safe and idempotent, which is not something you want when you are creating new data. `POST` is definitely the right choice here (under different circumstances `PUT` might also be a suitable candidate).

For further information on [`OPTIONS` consult the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS).