# pheonix api options call shows empty params

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am making a phoenix api for my react frontend and I am sending a post request with an object of objects, and I figured that I need to use options in the api to get them beause with post it just failed, but now the params are empty.
Why is that?

What I send:

```
axios
.post(PAYMENT_SERVER_URL, {
  description,
  email: token.email,
  source: token.id,
  subscriptionID
})
```

api router:

```
pipeline :api do
  plug(:accepts, ["json"])
end

scope "/api", MyApiWeb do
  pipe_through(:api)

  options("/users", UserController, :create)
end
```

api usercontroller

```
def create(conn, params) do
  IO.puts(options)
end
```

for now I'd be very happy with just logging it out.

Comment: So what happens on the front-end when you attempt a post? Are there any logged errors in the browser console?

Comment: @m3characters god bless you, it shows cors error

Comment: @jhonathanmyers Then you should install the CORS plug to send the necessary "CORS headers" that are needed for your API consuming frontend (see https://github.com/mschae/cors_plug and follow the installation instructions).